# How to get the division of 2 integers not to return 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

why `SET @H1 = CAST((@rCount / @poolTot) AS VARCHAR(50)) + '%'` keeps returning `0%`?

@H1 is a VARCHAR(50) while @rCount  and @poolTot are integers with values of 8 and 10. I should get something like .80%

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try CAST((@rCount / @poolTot) * 1.00 as varchar(50)) + '%'

Comment: integer division. fractions are truncated, so `0.8` -> `0`.

Comment: int/int will return int,so you get zero

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the result in decimal you can do something like

```
Declare @rCount as int=8;
declare @poolTot as int =10

select CAST((CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @rCount))  /
(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @poolTot))as varchar(50)) + '%'
```

Output will be like

[image]

Again if you want only two digit after decimal you can do something like

```
Declare @rCount as int=8;
declare @poolTot as int =10
declare @Temp as decimal(10,2)=(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @rCount))  /
(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), @poolTot))
    select convert(varchar(10),@Temp,2) + '%'
```

Than it will display like

[image]

Comment: I bet they want to multiply by 100 for %

Comment: Sorry didn't get you.

Comment: Only trying to help.  To go from fraction to % you multiply by 100.

Answer (score 0):

Either your dividend or divisor (or both) need to be a datatype with decimal places (decimal, float, etc).  One way of doing this is to muliply one of the numbers by 1.0, to force the conversion.  Or you can do an explicit conversion.

Your results may vary, depending on the data type you choose.  Using the first method below, you will get "0.80000000000000%".  If you cast it cast @poolTot as a float, like the second example, you will get "0.8%".  It really depends on what you want your results to look like.

```
DECLARE @H1 VARCHAR(50)
    ,@rCount INT = 8
    ,@poolTot INT = 10

SET @H1 = CAST(((@rCount)/ (@poolTot * 1.0)) AS VARCHAR(50)) + '%' 

SELECT @H1
```

_

```
DECLARE @H1 VARCHAR(50)
,@rCount INT = 8
,@poolTot INT = 10

SET @H1 = CAST(((@rCount)/ cast(@poolTot as float)) AS VARCHAR(50)) + '%' 

SELECT @H1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
SET @H1 = CAST((100 * @rCount / @poolTot) AS VARCHAR(50)) + '%'
```